# Why Pandas apply function returns None

Tags: python, pandas

I try to replace a character in some strings with conditions in a pandas dataframe column.
The function works but the rows of the dataframe display None.

```py
def char_replace(string):
    if string.startswith(tuple(list)):
        return string.replace("_", "-", 1)

df["col1"] = df["col1"].apply(char_replace)
```

Comment: you should have a default return in your function in case the string doesn't start with one of the values in the list

Comment: also please provide a possible input and a desired output showing what you're actually trying to accomplish. this would help any supporter to better understand your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need an else statement.  If the condition is not met, the function will proceed to the second return statement.

```
def char_replace(string):
    if string.startswith(tuple(list)):
        return string.replace("_", "-", 1)
    return string
df["col1"] = df["col1"].apply(char_replace)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  def char_replace(string):
    if string.startswith(tuple(list)):
        return string.replace("_", "-", 1)
    else:
         return string

df["col1"] = df["col1"].apply(char_replace)
```

need to have an option if string does not start with that paticular value